# Android Market - What about the 'Just In" section?

Tags: android, google-play

The "Just In" section (previous Android Market) used to include any app that was released and had not been updated for more that 2 weeks. This allowed smaller developers a chance to be at the top of the 'Just In' list for a few minutes (a great chance for some exposure and new downloads).

Removing these lists and adding the top new free/paid ones Google is basically saying that they only care about big developers with big marketing budgets? No small developer has a change to get his app noticed without advertising it external to the market anymore ??

These 2 links talk about this issue :

[link 1](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=69c2808d745db504&hl=en)

[link 2](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?hl=en&tid=275ab6ee0d2ed589)

My question is :

1. What are the exact rules to get into the "TOP NEW FREE", "TOP NEW PAID" and  "TRENDING" sections of the market ? Is there an official Google page explaining this ?
2. Is there any hope to get back to the previous system in the future ? Does Google really  want us to advertise the apps and get less income than the cost to advertise it ? Google's “Do No Evil” mantra is dead for good ?

I was wondering the small Android developer's opinion on this issue ? Any feedback is welcome ...

Comment: This question is not about Software development. App store questions are now off topic everywhere in the SE network, though you might be interested in the [App Stores](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) proposal on Area 51 (which needs some more help in definition, it seems).